# use grid.py with liblinear giving error

Tags: libsvm

I've been always using linear kernels in libsvm by following command

> python grid.py -log2c -1,10,1 -log2g -1,1,1 -t 0 data

But I now consider linear kernel in libsvm is different from liblinear. The example given in [liblinear official site](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/FAQ.html) gives me "ValueError: could not convert string to float: null"

> python grid.py -log2c -3,0,1 -log2g null -svmtrain ./train heart_scale

The other example in [liblinear documentation](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/liblinear.pdf) doesn't work neither, saying "Unknown option: -g" and TypeError in line 219: if rate is None: raise "get no rate".

> ./grid.py -log2c -14,14,1 -log2g 1,1,1 -svmtrain ./train news20.scale

I'm wondering what's the right way of using liblinear train with grid.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the latest version of grid.py from the the libsvm website. 
I happen to modifying my copy of grid.py at the moment and I can see it explicitly has handling for `-log2g null`.